# Spark RDD's - how do they work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, distributed-computing, rdd

I have a small Scala program that runs fine on a single-node. However, I am scaling it out so it runs on multiple nodes. This is my first such attempt. I am just trying to understand how the RDDs work in Spark so this question is based around theory and may not be 100% correct.

Let's say I create an RDD:
`val rdd = sc.textFile(file)`

Now once I've done that, does that mean that the file at `file` is now partitioned across the nodes (assuming all nodes have access to the file path)?

Secondly, I want to count the number of objects in the RDD (simple enough), however, I need to use that number in a calculation which needs to be applied to objects in the RDD - a pseudocode example:

```
rdd.map(x => x / rdd.size)
```

Let's say there are 100 objects in `rdd`, and say there are 10 nodes, thus a count of 10 objects per node (assuming this is how the RDD concept works), now when I call the method is each node going to perform the calculation with `rdd.size` as `10` or `100`? Because, overall, the RDD is size `100` but locally on each node it is only `10`. Am I required to make a broadcast variable prior to doing the calculation? This question is linked to the question below.

Finally, if I make a transformation to the RDD, e.g. `rdd.map(_.split("-"))`, and then I wanted the new `size` of the RDD, do I need to perform an action on the RDD, such as `count()`, so all the information is sent back to the driver node?

Comment: 'This question is linked to the question below.' --> ??

Comment: I think you meant `rdd.flatMap(_.split("-"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, the file (or parts of the file, if it's too big) is replicated to N nodes in the cluster (by default N=3 on HDFS). It's not an intention to split every file between all available nodes.

However, for you (i.e. the client) working with file using Spark should be transparent - you should not see any difference in `rdd.size`, no matter on how many nodes it's split and/or replicated. There are methods (at least, in Hadoop) to find out on which nodes (parts of the) file can be located at the moment. However, in simple cases you most probably won't need to use this functionality.

UPDATE: an article describing RDD internals: https://cs.stanford.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, for a calculation like: `rdd.filter(...).map(x => x * rdd.count)` is the `filter` step performed on each node before any node can perform the `map` step? Because, clearly, the `map` step depends upon the `filter` step already being performed on each node as the `map` contains `rdd.count`. Thanks again.

Comment: Naturally, because `map` is built upon `filter` (read about "lineage" concept in the article).

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's a good read, however, I'm now wondering what is the purpose of a Broadcast variable? Thanks again, appreciated!

Comment: The Berkeley link is dead now.

Answer (score 19):

> ```
> val rdd = sc.textFile(file)
> ```
>
> Does that mean that the file is now partitioned across the nodes?

The file remains wherever it was. The elements of the resulting `RDD[String]` are the lines of the file. The RDD is partitioned to match the natural partitioning of the underlying file system. The number of partitions does not depend on the number of nodes you have.

It is important to understand that when this line is executed it *does not* read the file(s). The RDD is a lazy object and will only do something when it must. This is great because it avoids unnecessary memory usage.

For example, if you write `val errors = rdd.filter(line => line.startsWith("error"))`, still nothing happens. If you then write `val errorCount = errors.count` now your sequence of operations will need to be executed because the result of `count` is an integer. What each worker core (executor thread) will do in parallel then, is read a file (or piece of file), iterate through its lines, and count the lines starting with "error". Buffering and GC aside, only a single line per core will be in memory at a time. This makes it possible to work with very large data without using a lot of memory.

> I want to count the number of objects in the RDD, however, I need to use that number in a calculation which needs to be applied to objects in the RDD - a pseudocode example:
>
> ```
> rdd.map(x => x / rdd.size)
> ```

There is no `rdd.size` method. There is `rdd.count`, which counts the number of elements in the RDD. `rdd.map(x => x / rdd.count)` will not work. The code will try to send the `rdd` variable to all workers and will fail with a `NotSerializableException`. What you can do is:

```
val count = rdd.count
val normalized = rdd.map(x => x / count)
```

This works, because `count` is an `Int` and can be serialized.

> If I make a transformation to the RDD, e.g. `rdd.map(_.split("-"))`, and then I wanted the new size of the RDD, do I need to perform an action on the RDD, such as `count()`, so all the information is sent back to the driver node?

`map` does not change the number of elements. I don't know what you mean by "size". But yes, you need to perform an action, such as `count` to get anything out of the RDD. You see, no work at all is performed until you perform an action. (When you perform `count`, only the per-partition count will be sent back to the driver, of course, not "all the information".)

Comment: I made a [tag:Python] example based on your answer in [the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/833/introduction-to-apache-spark#t=20160817171702245426), if you like it, you can include it in your answer!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It answers all parts completely and correctly.